# For each model a new connection? Is that right?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a Node.js application through Express.js foundation and my knowledge lead me to create a `models` folder and a file for each model. Ok, so far, so good — but the point is: each model of mine has the following fragment of code on its top:

```
var mongoose    = require ('mongoose')
    , database  = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
```

Am I repeating myself doing this? I'm not searching for "the best approach ever", but doing this is not a bad design thing?

If this is something normal, could someone explain me why this behavior happens? Couldn't I create an organic mechanism to establish a connection and just distribute its properties for the entire application?

I already worked on Rails, C# and PHP and I've never see something like this before. Probably because database connections were for me something very abstract — I touched just a few times on the connection bridge.

<sub>DISCLAIMER: My question is *really* very specific. I just want to know if there's a way to announce the database connection from one file to the rest of the application.</sub>

Comment: Could you explain.. If you want a connection returned from a different file or you want to know if creating a saperate db connection is good?

Comment: Please leave a comment for downvotes people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not typical.

Unless you have a specific need to do something else, call [`mongoose.connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) once during app startup and register all models using [`mongoose.model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model).

This lets your app share a common connection pool.  You can tweak the size of the connection pool via the options provided in the `mongoose.connect` call.